# How do I get an object from local storage after json.stringify()

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am currently creating a login page with ReactJS. This page utilises an API which has an 'authorise' function confirming whether the entered details are authorised to use the API. To handle the API calls, I have created a class which has a function for each possible API call.
If the user is able to login successfully (if the authorise function returns a status of 200) they are redirected to a 'ProjectSelect' page/component. From this Project Select page the user will be able to select a specific project from their project list.
Now, here is where the problem lies. I need to now use the API instance from the 'Login' component in the 'ProjectSelect' component. The way in which I am currently trying to do this involves storing it in local storage as such:

Login.jsx:

```
import {API} from 'filepath';
const api = new API();

async function loginUser(email, password, appid) {
  return api.authorise(email, password, appid);
}

export default function Login() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState();
  const [password, setPassword] = useState();
  const [appid, setAppId] = useState();

  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const response = await loginUser(
      email,
      password,
      appid
    );
    console.log(response);
    if (response.status === 200) {
      swal("Success", "Logged In", "success", {
        buttons: false,
        timer: 2000,
      })
      .then((value) => {
        localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.data.access_token);
        localStorage.setItem('api', JSON.stringify(api));

        window.location.href = "/bimpluslogin";
      });
    } else {
      swal("Failed", "Login Failed", "error");
    }
  }
```

ProjectSelect.jsx:

```
const api = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('api'));
let allProjects = api.getAllProjects(); // Error occurs here ('getAllProjects()' does not exist)
```

I am aware that if you JSON.stringify() an object it will only take the key values leaving it basically unusable when parsed back through the JSON.

What I've tried:
I have tried to create a new API instance in the ProjectSelect component and storing the auth details in local storage however that causes a lot of issues and doesn't allow me to use all of the functions.
I would appreciate any suggestions on how to store an object from one component and then use that exact same object in another component. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: @caTS the error says that the function I am trying to call does not exist. It does not recognise 'api' as an instance of the 'API' class anymore because it is only holding the key values of the previous instance.